# How to make a dictionary in java?

Tags: java, api, dictionary

I am trying to make a offline dictionary in java where you enter a word in a text field and the meaning of that word. Does anyone know of an API that can be used to make this dictionary? 
Any alternatives  will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

A *dictionary* is nothing but a `Map`. It *maps* a keyword to a description (or a collection of descriptions).

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = TreeMap<String, String>();
dictionary.put("hello", "polite greeting");
System.out.println(dictionary.get("hello"));
```

A trivial starter is using a *properties* file and loading the data with/into a `Properties` instance.

File extract:

```
key=provides access to a value
value=maps to a key
hello=polite greeting
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of an api that can be used to make this dictionary?

The most obvious starting point is the `Map` interface: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to implement it.