# the correct way to make a dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to make a dictionary (English to English) for my java program. i was only thinking about finding a database of words and meanings, then i run a search query for each word to get it's meaning. i searched `StackoverFlow` and saw the same questions about how to make a dictionary. 
every one had recommended using the `Map` class. for example:[How to make a dictionary in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480292/how-to-make-a-dictionary-in-java)
is it the correct way?

Comment: yep. The closest thing you have to a dictionary in java is the Map interface and its subclasses. Take a look at HashMap

Comment: What makes you think that you will get a different answer this time?

Comment: @assylias what about the way i was thinking about?

Comment: @RNJ i don't understand how, you mean i must make a big HashMap, and gives it each word and it's meaning ?

Comment: If you want a database of words and meanings already available for you, SO is not the place to find that, search google. You might endup finding a webservice that gives you what u need.

By Map you can implement your dictionary, but the words and meaning are not readily available for you!

Comment: You will need `MultiMap<A,B>`, which is simply `Map<A, List<B>>`

Comment: @RobinChander NO, i just want to know what the correct way is

Comment: it depends on you requirements. for example: if you find a webservice, then you can simply pass your word to the webservice and it will return you the meaning. Here, you only need a Map if you want to cache the words. Basically it depends what your requirmeents are

Answer (score 1):

An embedded database is not as difficult too. Try a couple of examples, with different operation strategies. The database can be kept persistent. The java Derby database is there, but H2SQL and some others are maybe worth even more.

You need more plumbing than a Map, but additionally you can do *queries*, like for synonyms - if you are delving deeper into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a map is suitable for a dictionary implementation. From `Map`'s JavaDoc:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate
>   keys; each key can map to at most one value.
>
> This interface takes the place of the Dictionary class, which was a
>   totally abstract class rather than an interface.

Comment: you mean i must give the map all the words and their meanings?

Comment: Yes, or maybe retrieve the data from some database and load it into the map.

Comment: why? so what?! when i can run a query on my database and retrieve my needed data and directly show them to user, why should i use a Map in middle?

Comment: `Map` is an object in the RAM, hence accessing and manipulating it is much faster than accessing and manipulating the database.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary insofar as it maps words to definitions can also encompass mapping words to words.

So the use of a Map makes most sense, specifically you can have your `Key`:

```
public class Key  
{  
     private String keyName;
     ...
}
```

and your `value` be a set of keys:

```
Map<Key,Set<Key>> dictionary = ...;  
Set<Key> catKeys = new HashSet<Key>();  
catKeys.add('kitty');  
catKeys.add('kitten');  //technically true just a small one  
dictionary.put(new Key('Cat'), catKeys);
```

Comment: That seems overcomplicated when a `Map<String, String>` would probably work, no?

Comment: @assylias the use of the `String` api is one of the biggest pitfalls of Java development.  Case in point this presentation by Joshua Bloch: http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf

Comment: It probably is - but using a String to represent a word or a sentence does not sound like an inappropriate usage... Since your current key implementation is just a string, I don't see any reason not to use a string directly...

Comment: @assylias I am passing around a Key object, it is coincidental it is made up of a String.  I could have 17 functions in there but it was unnecessary for this example